# using WHERE in my Insert query statement

Tags: c#, select, oledb, where-clause

```
string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
           Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Timetable\Timetable\bin\Debug\timetabledata.accdb";

//create the database query
string query = "SELECT * FROM relation";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conString);
conn.Open();

// create the DataSet
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

// create the adapter and fill the DataSet
OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
adapter.Fill(ds);

int f = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < f; i++)
    {
     // create the database query
     string query1 = "SELECT * FROM [time] Where classid= '"+
                               ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]+"'";
     DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
     OleDbDataAdapter adapter1;
     adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(query1, conn);
     adapter1.Fill(ds1);
     MessageBox.Show(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
     }
```

the result that i get not true in message box that i want the id of all rows having the same classid but in message box that i use just to verification before o continue i see the id of time table without be consider where

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Don't assume the SQL engine is at fault here.  It's *much* more likely that you've made an incorrect assumption somewhere in your code.  Do some debugging to find out what.  Examine the runtime query, run that query against the database manually with and without the `WHERE` clause, examine the results.  Without knowing anything about your data, we can't possibly know what the values should be here.

Comment: thanks.. i do but no result.. i try again

Comment: i use "like" instead of "=" and i have the result that i want but it's true?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this part be changed from...

```
string query1 = "SELECT * FROM [time] Where classid+ '"+
                               ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]+"'";
```

to...

```
string query1 = "SELECT * FROM [time] Where classid = '"+
                               ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]+"'";
```

You seem to be using a plus symbol (**+**) instead of equals (**=**).

Comment: i edit.. it is not the problem.. i wrote correctly in my code

Comment: It's definitely one of the problems, what is the value of `ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]`?

Comment: its classid for each 'i' i have a value : 1-4-5-7-4-3-1

Comment: when i use like instead = , i get the true result : it's true to use it

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
public DataSet GetRelations()
{
    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [relation]", connection))
        {
            var results = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(results);
            return results;
        }
    }
}

public DataSet GetTimeResults()
{
    DataSet dsRelations = GetRelations();

    var dsResults = new DataSet();
    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)) 
    {
        connection.Open();

        foreach (DataRow row in dsRelations.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            using (var command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [time] Where classid = ?", connection))
            {
                // not entirey sure what the value of row.ItemArray[2] is ?
                command.Parameters.Add(row.ItemArray[2]);
                using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dsResults);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return dsResults;
}
```

Just invoke it and use it as you see fit:

```
public void Test()
{
    DataSet dsTimeResults = GetTimeResults();
    // Do whatever you need with the results
}
```